# Cannot enable innodb_read_only on slave

Tags: mariadb, slave

I am trying to make a MariaDB slave instance read only. From what I understand, `read_only` option is not truly readonly as users with super privilege can still write to the database.

`super_read_only` is not yet supported by MariaDB, but there is an open feature request for it.

I also came across `innodb_read_only`. But `innodb_read_only` is set to `OFF`, even when I add `-innodb-read-only=1` to mysqld arguments.

Is `innodb_read_only` allowed on a slave server?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. If a replication master is writing to the slave, it can't be read only!

Comment: I don't want the server to be readonly. I just want to prevent someone (with super privilege) from writing to the slave by mistake. Not granting super privilege to users is the obvious answer. I am interested in finding out whether there is another solution.

Comment: The various flavors of `read_only` apply to users, not the Replication stream.

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?  There are several mentions of those flags in the Changelogs.

Comment: I am using  10.2.